# Github get link of current project in live preview

Tags: github, github-pages, plunker

I upload my project to github and I want to see the project live in link.

I tried to do that with plunker but I don't see any import option.

I saw github users upload their project then they put link with 'xxxx.github.com' 
(github domain) when I press it I see the project in preview live.

how can I do that?

my directory structure
[image]

in the src

[image]

github link
[github link to project- shows only the background color](https://adirzoari.github.io/src/)

[github link](https://adirzoari.github.io/)

[github project](https://github.com/adirzoari/adirzoari.github.io/)

Comment: You already added the tag, so I wonder why you could not find this: https://pages.github.com/

Comment: i upload with the instruction. I see the project in github but when I link to the address I don't see that. 404 error

Comment: Do you have gh-pages branch in your repository?

Comment: what is gh-pages? I used this tutorial @https://pages.github.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use gh-pages.

Make a new orphan branch called gh-pages. Keep your index html page in the root directory of that branch. Your project will now be live.

Comment: that's what i did but it show me just the background color without all the functionality and the text... it's look like it's loading but forever... I build angular 2 project..

Comment: Can you post the directory structure or the link to the repo if it is not private

Comment: sure. I edited my post and publish. the second photo is the src folder

Comment: I also added the links to github you can see exactly what i see.in the first link is the "index.html" - i can see only the background color

Comment: do you see anything can help?

Comment: I think the problem is not how you have hosted the website on github, because when I git cloned the project in my system and tried to open the index.html, it still gives me the same yellow page with the `Loading` text.

Comment: yes, but when i run it on my pc with ng serve it works fine. what do you think?

Comment: I am not familiar with angular but I think something like this might be able to help you: `ng github-pages:deploy`

Comment: after I install it I need to upload again to github?

Comment: Again I am not familiar with angular js at all, but generally you would build your project and upload the generated files on gh-pages.
In simpler words, make sure the html page you are uploading on gh-pages, runs successfully on your local to produce the desired webpage. I am not sure how you would do this with angular but I think it provides  
[this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli-ghpages) to deploy the relevant files to gh-pages